# Windows explorer crashes every 30 seconds

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, crash

My windows explorer crashes in every 30 seconds or so. On the title bar, it shows "Not Responding", system hangs for a while and after clicking on the window itself, everything fades in white color.

Beauty: After 30 seconds of hang, everything resumes back automatically. It works as if nothing has happened.

This is really annoying. Happening since last week.

Please help.

Comment: do you run any heavy application that consumes entire `RAM`? Also what is your hardware config?

Comment: Whenever this happens to me it has been a network problem: do you have any network drives with assigned drive letters?

Comment: @vembu - No Heavy application. Configuration: Core i5, 4GB RAM.

Comment: @AFH - Yes I have network drives. But I seldom access them. I am on a office's network most of the time. But, the system was working fine a few days back. Network drives never created an issue(since I never accessed them!).

Comment: Yes, but explorer accesses them, whether you explicitly do so or not. See if the problem persists if you remove the network drives: they are easy to restore from a drop-down list. There may be a new network problem.

Comment: @AFH - How can I remove network drives? **(Also, how would I restore them back.)**

Comment: Under the **Tools** menu you will find **Map Network Drive...** and **Disconnect Network Drive...**. The latter has a pull-down list of recently connected drives, so all you need to do is remember which letter was associated (if it matters).